# How to get reference to current textbox in a table which contains 50 textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically i have table with 50 rows and each row has 2 td. One for input and next one has label and everything is dynamic.

Refer this image 
[image]

**Dilemma**
The user enters a number in the textbox(how do i know which one if i dont want to loop through all of them?) and on enter key event i call a javascript function which checks if its valid and adds corresponding message to the next tds label.
How to know the reference of input without looping through all the textboxes as i call the function on each textbox input's enter function?

Comment: Is the table created in the HTML file or is it dynamically generated with JS or something else? And what is it's id? Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: no the table is not created dynamically but tit contents are for ex error message and i can use jquery

Comment: If none of the answers below are enough for what you are asking, perhaps you should ask with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, based upon the (limited available information), though requires you to handle validation yourself, obviously:

```
function yourDefinedFunction(){
    // you need to handle the validating yourself, somehow.
    return false;
}

/* binds the 'keypress' to the 'tr' elements, which 'listens' to see
   if they take place on/in a 'td' element */
$('tbody tr').on('keypress', 'td', function(e){
    /* 'this' is the 'td' element,
        'e.target' is the element within the 'td' that received the event
    var cell = this,
        target = e.target;

    // if the key pressed is the enter key, *and* the target was the input, then:
    if (e.which === 13 && target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {

        // you determine whether the entry is valid, however you want:
        var validity = yourDefinedFunction() || 'valid';

        // and set the text of the next 'td' element to reflect that validity:
        $(cell).next('td').text(validity);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8qvju/1/).

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! And thank *you* for the accept! =D

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a good example without knowing specifically what you're trying to do, but something like this would work:

```
$('tr > td:first > input').keyup(function(e) {
    //jQuery object representing the input box the user typed into
    var input_box = $(this);

    //get which key was pressed
    var key_pressed = e.which;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the "change" event for the textbox such as: first add `class='myTextboxClass'` to your text boxes markup.

```
$(mytableselector).on('change','.myTextboxClass', function(){
   var me = this; // the one that changed
   $(this).val();//value of that textbox
});
```

set the sibling text:

```
$(mytableselector).on('change','.myTextboxClass', function(){
   var me = this; // the one that changed
   $(this).val();//value of that textbox
   $(me).parent('td').next('td').html('Invalid entry');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector for table").on("keyup", "input[type=\"text\"]", function(ev) {
    if (ev.which !== 13) {
        return;
    }

    alert($(this).value());
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YfSF3/)

Comment: No need to escape the interpreter for `input[type=\"text\"]`, you're encased in a string already, so you're fine just doing `input[type=text]`

Comment: [_Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks._](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy You're right, the value doesn't **have to** be enclosed with quotation marks, but the CSS standard is to include them - `name="value"`. It's really unnecessary, but it is correct, and I do this as well

Comment: Then just use single quotation marks instead of escaping the interpreter and taking a performance hit

Comment: that said, i don't see a good reason to use escaped double quotes instead of single quotes there

Comment: Technically, it should/could be `'input[type="text"]'`. The CSS spec says to use double quotes anyways

Comment: yeah, that's what i would do too. besides not having to hit shift, one good reason to use single quotes by default in javascript is so you don't have to escape double quotes in html tags. unless, of course, you use single quotes in your html tags ...

Comment: @sgroves Good point. That's another argument though :) I don't why, but I can't help but always use double quotes, unless it's much easier with single quotes. It's just some habit I've always been stuck with. It's nice in JavaScript, because you can use either `"` or `'`, where they may have different meanings in some other languages

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Performance hit? Compared to creating a jQuery object? Not really... I've started programming with c/c++ so for me a single quote is for single characters and double quotes for strings. Therefor just an old habit of mine...

Comment: @andreas I don't know where you came up with the idea that I was comparing it to creating a jQuery object, but yea, I'm talking about escaping the interpreter here....nothing to do with making a jQuery Object. TMYK.

Comment: @andreas using that paradigm might be confusing to others reading your code. conventional JS style is to pick one or the other to use for all strings. that said, you might not care, which is fine.

Comment: @sgroves Why should it be confusing? It will always be a string, just that I stick with single quotes for chars and double quotes for strings (without mixing them).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy [What performance hit](http://jsperf.com/escaped-attribute-vs-mixed-quotes)?

Comment: @andreas i was just trying to point out that basically no one uses the c++ quoting style because it doesn't make any sense in javascript. so it's likely to look weird to anyone who might read your code. like i said, if you don't care, then no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the on... events, this will point to the current input.
Example:

```
<td>
  <textarea onchange="foo(this)">
</td>
<td>
  Hello
</td>
...
function (input) {
  input.parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

This example would change the value of the td to the right of the textarea to the value of the textarea.
(Not very robust code, but it's just an example.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tableID :text").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which !== 13) { //check if the key pressed is Enter
        return;           // if it is not, stop execution of code
    }
    var nextTD = $(this).closest('td').next();
    //your code goes after this line
});
```

After the declaration of nextTD you can insert your code to update the td content as you prefer.

P.s.: I'm assuming that your table is in the form of the example linked below

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jg7P4/)